# Creating a view overlay over MPMoviePlayerViewController

Tags: iphone, view, metadata, overlay, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am developing an app that plays internet radio. Owing to my lack of skill, i have only used the stock MPMoviePlayerController.
This is so far been able to play a few m3u streams (like the 'feeling floyd' station)

However, i was wondering if there was any way to have this MPMoviePlayerViewController to show me extra information.. like the song that is playing (which information i was able to extract form teh metadata.)

I can get this information all right, but how do i put it on the screen?
Can I make an overlay or something? (the centre of the MPMovieplayer is taken up by the quicktime background... it would be great if i could use an overlay on this space to show current music information or whatever.)

Is this overlay thing possible? if not, is there *any other* way?

Thank you very much! 
V

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want your own custom view over the player you can add it as a subview to the player's view as `[player.view addSubview:yourView];`

Comment: @mvishnu: Happy coding. Pls vote up the answers when you are able to

Comment: it does n't work when user do full screen of video,at that time overlay removes itself.check it.!!!

Answer (score 1):

Get the `moviePlayer` property of `MPMoviePlayerViewController`. I think you should be able to to do this `[moviePlayer.view addSubview:myView]`.